# Continuous functions of $(0,1)$ form a metric space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

If $X$ is the set of continuous functions on $(0,1)$ and for every $x,y\in X$

$$
E(x,y) = [t\in(0,1):x(t)\neq y(t)],
$$

($E(x,y)$ is the union of disjoint open intervals), and $\rho(x,y)$ the sum of the lengths of these intervals, how does one prove the triangle inequality?

Since $E(x,y)$ is the union of disjoint open intervals over $(0,1)$, one can see $E(x,y)$ as a countable union of open subsets of $(0,1)$, i.e $E = \cup_{j=1}^n V_j$ and $\rho(x,y) = \sum_{j=1}^n l_j$, where $l_j$ is the interval length of $V_j$. I don't know how to justify that a "middle" function $z$ will yield $\rho(x,y)\leq \rho(x,z) + \rho(z,y)$.

Comment: Oh I see. Well if at some $t$, $x(t)\neq y(t)$, then $x(t)-z(t) \neq y(t) - z(t)$, and in particular $x(t)-z(t)\neq 0$ or $y(t)-z(t)\neq 0$ (because they can't both be equal). This establishes $E(x,y) \subset E(x,z) \cup E(y,z)$, and then you might have to fuss around with measuring lengths of intervals when the intervals may get cut up differently, but basically this implies the result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $\rho(x,y)$ is essentially the Lebesgue measure of $E(x,y)$, and this can be used to elimiate the fuss of cutting up the intervals differently mentioned in @Calvin_Khor's comment.

We could bring a more general perspective into the metric.

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F, P)$ be a probability space, and $(M, d)$ be a bounded metric space, then the set of measurable functions $f:\Omega\rightarrow M$ is equipped with the metric $$d(x,y):=\int_\Omega d(x(t), y(t))dt$$

The proof for this is pretty straightforward using $d$ satisfies the triangle inequality.

In your case, $\Omega = (0, 1)$ and $P$ is the Lebesgue measure. $M=\mathbb R$ equipped with the discrete metric $d(x,y)=1$ whenever $x\not=y$, and $\rho(x,y)$ is the probability of $x\not=y$.

Comment: Well, that just abstracts away the fuss into the subadditivity of the measure (which I'm not convinced OP knows about). But +1 :)

Comment: I agree. Just cannot help but bring in the general picture when there is one.

Comment: @Justauser Uhmm you meant that if $\rho$ es the Lebesgue measure, then it fulfills $\rho(E(x,z)\cup E(y,z))\leq \rho(E(x,z)) + \rho(E(y,z))$?

Comment: @user2820579
 Yes, that's what I mean.